# How can I filter data from file when sending to two different locations using BizTalk?

Tags: biztalk

If I want to send a file e.g. XML to two different locations making it two different folders using BizTalk. But at the same time I want to filter the data from this files then how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want certain XML files to be sent only to a certain location when it matches certain criteria, then what you need to do is to have a promoted property in your message context that you can then have as part of your send port Filter. This promoted property can either be a field of the message that you have promoted or a message context only promoted property that you have set either in a Pipeline or Orchestration.

If however you want to filter the data in a XML file in a Send port, then you would need to have a map on the send port that selected the data from the source XML payload and map that to the target XML payload.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean filter which data you want to process before sending, you can use `content based routing`. See below links which ever you prefer.

[Using esb toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/esb-toolkit/how-to-implement-content-based-routing-using-message-context-properties)

[Using orchestration](http://musial.tk/2012/05/05/biztalk-wif-wf-tutorial-part-2-3a-message-content-based-routing-orchestration/)

But if you mean by filter the contents by modifying source xml, you need to:

> 1. Create a map using your payload `xml` as source and target
> 2. Add your map in send port's outbound map.

[image]

Comment: You can also set context properties in pipelines for routing purposes using the BRE Pipeline Framework  https://github.com/mbrimble/brepipelineframework/